# Dom Document generation by APEX code

Tags: apex, xml, dom

I am writing APEX to generate DOM document. 
I want to generate `<TOTALVOLUME units="m3">1.0</TOTALVOLUME>.`
Parent node for TOTALVOLUME is consignmentBody and I am trying Below code to generate the required.

```
consignmentBody.addChildElement('TOTALVOLUME', null, null).setAttribute('units', 'm3'); 
    consignmentBody.addChildElement('TOTALVOLUME', null, null).addTextNode('1.0');
```

I know that I am using 2 addchildelement, Kindly help me to get the required as I am not able to generate with only one childelement.

Comment: Want to generate <TOTALVOLUME units="m3">1.0</TOTALVOLUME>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setAttribute to create attribute on XML node. See documentation for [XMLNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm).

Example 1:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
Dom.Xmlnode rootNode = doc.createRootElement('TestReport', null, null);

Dom.Xmlnode childNode = rootNode.addChildElement('detail', null, null);               
childNode.addTextNode('1.0') ;             
childNode.setAttribute('Amount','1000');  

String xmlString = doc.toXmlString();
System.debug('xmlString =' + xmlString);
```

Your code can be like this

```
Dom.Xmlnode childNode = rootNode.addChildElement('TOTALVOLUME', null, null);               
childNode.setAttribute('units','m3');
childNode.addTextNode('1.0') ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time Dhanik.